# segmentation fault with rm sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, segmentation-fault

I tried to remove sqlite with

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sqlite3.so.0.6.8
```

however is is giving me a Segmentation Fault

I have two copies of both libsqlite3.so.0 and libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu and /usr/local/lib.

I was having problems with sql so I was planning on removing it and reinstalling. I was able to remove libsqlite3.so.0 from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu (with rm) but when removing libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 from the same location, I now get a segfault. Also copying the libsqlite files from the /usr/local/lib directory gives me a segfault.

Reinstalling sqlite3 (both via apt-get and the source) also give me a segmentation fault error.

Any ideas how to reinstall sqlite (or remove all sqlite files and reinstall)?

Comment: If `rm` segfaults you have bigger issues than anything to do with sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260353/segmentation-fault-when-using-su-or-sudo).

Reinstalling all the sqlite packages via aptdcon did the trick.